# Running Pika Threads to create multiple connections to RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I am creating a component that would read to 4 queues, and for each queue would be threaded of up to 5 threads. The problem is, only 1 Queue with 5 threads is being initialized.

Here is the Code for What I am doing:

```
        # Set up RabbitMQ connection and channel TODO parameter config
        #self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        # Declare the queues
        for queue_name in self.queue_names:
            self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)

    def consume(self):
        # Create a thread pool executor for consuming messages
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.num_threads) as executor:
            # Submit a task for each queue and thread
            for queue_name in self.queue_names:
                for i in range(self.num_threads):
                    executor.submit(self._consume_thread, queue_name)


    def _consume_thread(self, queue_name):
        print(f'Conenction Established: {queue_name}')
        # Set up a new connection and channel for each thread
        #connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()

        # Declare the queue
        channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)
        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count= 100)
        # Start consuming messages
        channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=self._on_message)
        channel.start_consuming()

    def _on_message(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        try:
            # Process the message here
            #print(f"Received message from {method.routing_key}: {body}")
            message = json.loads(body)
            self.correlator.correlate(message)
            # Acknowledge the message
            channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        except:
            pass
            

    def close(self):
        # Close the RabbitMQ connection
        self.connection.close()

def main():
    consumer = RabbitMQConsumer(queue_names=['C1PERFQ', 'C1DESCQ', 'C1EVENTQ', 'C1RELQ'], num_threads=5)
    print("Starting")
    consumer.consume()
    print("Consuming")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize the logger once as the application starts up
    with open('./logging.yaml', 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    # Create logs folder if it does not exists
    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.makedirs('logs')
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Now Logging %s ', __name__)
    main()
```

I am expecting that it would initialize 20 connections since there are 4 queues and 5 threads of it. But only the first in the list is being initialized.

Comment: Ok, I found the Solution Guys... Instead of using Concurrent Threading, I just went to use the basic threading function...